# How to get the last "step" in a step function using d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, line, interpolation

I'm using a simple line graph in d3 with interpolation of "step-after".

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });
// Note that with step-after, the last data point shows no "step". Why?
line.interpolate('step-after');
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/hrabinowitz/zCmHw/1/) This shows a horizontal line after each data point **except the last one**.

For small numbers of points, if you think of the x axis as time, this is unintuitive, because the last interval does not show up.

I've tried to simply add an extra point at the end of the data with null or NaN value.

```
// add a null entry after last date
var DAY_IN_MILLIS = 24*60*60*1000;
dataArray.push(
    {date: new Date(dataArray[dataArray.length-1].date.getTime() + DAY_IN_MILLIS), 
     close:NaN});
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/hrabinowitz/abJLf/49/)

This gives a better appearance, but it triggers an svg parsing error in the path for the line, because of the NaN value.

I've also tried to use the line.defined() function, but this does not help either, since if I make the additional point undefined, then no step is drawn at the end of the real data.

Can anyone suggest a way to handle this problem without triggering a parsing exception?

Comment: Have you tried using `step-before`?

Comment: Yes. To my thinking, step-before is even less intuitive. It shows the horizontal "step" line **before** the data point it is associated with.

Comment: How about replicating the last data point and not drawing a circle for it? http://jsfiddle.net/zCmHw/4/

Comment: Thanks, Lars, that is a nice approach.  It avoids messing with NaNs, nulls, and defined().  I still think this is a flaw in d3, or svg itself, but perhaps one that doesn't affect many users.

Comment: I don't really see it as a flaw -- you have a choice of `step-before` and `step-after`, which provide generic functionality not specific to time series. To achieve what you want, you have to extend the line beyond the last data point, which is not something a library should do on its own.