# Missing Initial Step from Step Plot D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is an issue that I have not discovered a clean fix for.

Within my step plot below:

http://jsfiddle.net/q47r3pyk/7/

You can see that I have a vertical blue line at the start of the chart.

This is because I added an additional x-value and y-value so that the first step will show up in the step plot.

If you look at

http://jsfiddle.net/q47r3pyk/8/

where I remove the first dummy entry with

x-value of `"12-Jul-14"`
y-value of `0`

The first step of my step plot will have a width of zero.

Is there a recommended approach within d3.js for having the first step show without losing the last step by using `step-after`? or a fix for removing the vertical blue line that shows up with my hack of adding a dummy value?

Step is specified in

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) {
               return x(d.x);
           })
        .y(function (d) {
               return y(+d.y);
           })
        .interpolate("step-after");
```

Comment: Please note: if you change from `step-before` to `step-after`, it's "not only" the first and the last step that changes. Everything in between will be different too, visually. So e.g. for 17thNov, you have either a line at 4.1 (`step-after`) or a line at 5.2 (`step-before`). So you are selling a different story to the user. So my suggestion: Make sure you use the correct step function depending on the needs. Once that is decided, add a point at the start or the end (as you suggest). There is no avoiding that imho, as you need to tell the viz where to start/stop (there is no way of knowing)

Comment: see also comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009444/how-to-get-the-last-step-in-a-step-function-using-d3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could clip the path using SVG clip-path:

```
svg.append("clipPath").attr("id", "canvasClip")
.append("rect")
.attr("height", height)
.attr("width", width)
```

Then reference the clip-path on your line:

```
svg.append("path")
        .datum(formatted_data)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line)
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#canvasClip)")
```

Here's the fiddle, it seems to work fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/q47r3pyk/11/

But, ultimately, I think this is a case where the interpolator is acting as it should, and you really shouldn't be thinking about how to subvert it but rather whether it's the right interpolator for your data. In this case, I'd say no, and suggest you use "step" as your interpolator instead of "step-before" or "step-after". I think that would give you the result you're looking for and lines up well with your interactivity.

Answer (score 2):

Is this help?

I have tried several times, i think it is the best result i have got, hope it helps!

```
x.domain(d3.extent(x_axis, function (d) {
    return parseDate(d);
})).nice(x_axis.length);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/p04xuubh/)